# How to un-shrink hard space by windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, hard-drive, partitioning

I shrinked 150 GB out of my 500 GB hard space by windows 7, in order to install ubuntu beside windows on my laptop.

Now some amount of that 150GB is free and I need to have it back on my windows.

What should I do?

- Is it possible to creatively re-attach the free parts of that 150 GB to the windows, in a way that the ubuntu's information will be still available?

P.S: If it is possible, the windows-based solutions are more preferred than ubuntu-based solutions.

[image]

Comment: Can you post a Disk Management screenshot?

Comment: http://8pic.ir/images/0spr769oeiox3pbjgond.jpg

Comment: You have allocated all the space on your hdd.

Comment: I technically don't know the function of shrinking. Someone told me to do that.

Answer (score 1):

> I shrinked 150 GB out of my 500 GB hard space by windows 7

It seems you shrinked about 240 GB, not 150 GB.

> Now some amount of that 150GB is free and I need to have it back on my windows.

How?

- as space on `C:` partition (extend): this is not possible without formatting Ubuntu partition
- as another partition: this may be possible:

  - get an Ubuntu bootable DVD/USB
  - boot from it and launch GParted
  - Shrink the root partition of Ubuntu how much you want / you are allowed
  - leave the free space... free (no partitions on it)
  - restart into Windows
  - go to Disk Management and create a new partition in the unused space (There is the possibility it wouln't allow that!)

Comment: I would use **gparted** for both operations, and move Ubuntu's lower boundary up and Win7's boundary up to fill the freed space.